# how to insert data into more than one table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench, data-migration

I have a customer table (`id`, `name` ,`address`,.....) and a customer account table (`acntid`, `name`, `address`.....) and `Datasource` table has (`name`,`adresss`,`email`,`zipcode` etc). Now, i want to insert name and address from data source to `customer` and `customeraccount` table at the same time. Should we have to write scripts or procedures or triggers or anything else?

Comment: You should insert that information into one table and use a `join` to access it for the other.

Comment: thanks for ur suggestion.. but i am having many tables similar to the senerio showed above.can u suggest me anything which makes my work faster

Comment: Formatted table fields

Comment: wat.. i didnt get u..

Answer (score 1):

Fire Both Query At the Same Time

```
$result=mysql_query(select name,address from datasourcetable);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
 { 
   Insert Into customer(name,address) Values($row['name'],$row['address'])
  Insert Into customeraccount(name,address)Values(($row['name'],$row['address']) }
```

Comment: thank u... this works if i have only one data source table and two tables which i have to insertBut i had ONE DATASOURCE AND MANY TABLES WHERE I SHOULD GET DATA FROM DATA SOURCE TABLE AND INSERT INTO MANY TABLES.

Comment: Ok the Fetch Your Data From Datasource table And Insert into Both Table  `$result=mysql_query(select name,address from datasourcetable);             while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ Insert Into customer(name,address) Values($row['name'],$row['address'])
Insert Into customeraccount(name,address) Values(($row['name'],$row['address']) }`

Comment: kk .......consider Customer is the parent table and customer has many child tables. now if i insert data in parent table ,data should automatically go into child tables at once..is it possible..

Comment: yes its possible Fire Insert Query for parent and child table at same time

Comment: yes u can also use triggers or also do this work with query